# IF statement inside MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need some help to complete this trigger. I try it but I don't know what is wrong.

This is the code:

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TRIGGER attendance_clock AFTER INSERT ON alldevicerecord
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE check INT;
    SET check= 1;
    IF (check % 2 == 0) THEN
      INSERT into designation(emp_id, clock_date, clock_in) VALUES (new.id, new.time, new.time);
      check  = check + 1;
    ELSE
      UPDATE designation SET clock_out = new.time WHERE emp_id = NEW.id;
      check = check + 1;
    END IF
END$$

delimiter ;
```

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: what are you trying to do at all?

Comment: try **set** check = check + 1;

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TRIGGER attendance_clock AFTER INSERT ON alldevicerecord
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE `check` INT;
  SET `check` = 1;
  IF (`check` % 2 = 0) THEN
    INSERT INTO designation (emp_id, clock_date, clock_in) VALUES(new.id, new.time, new.time);
    SET `check`  = `check` + 1;
  ELSE
    UPDATE designation SET clock_out = new.time WHERE emp_id = NEW.id;
    SET `check`  = `check` + 1;
  END IF;
END$$

delimeter ;
```