# Trigger with IF condition in MySQL

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers, phpmyadmin

I have a problem with a trigger on my database (I'm using phpmyadmin). When I Insert a new row in my table 'customer'.

```
+-------------+------+------------+--------------+  
| id_customer | name |  group     |  subscribed  |  
+-------------+------+------------+--------------+  
|    1        | John | Business   |    true      |  
|    2        | Rose | Particular |    true      |    
|    3        | Ann  | Business   |    false     |    
+-------------+------+------------+--------------+
```

I want to add a new row in my table 'groups_customer'

```
+----------+-------------+  
| id_group | id_customer |  
+----------+-------------+  
|   3      |     1       |  
|   4      |     2       |  
+----------+-------------+
```

So in case I Insert a new customer that is subscribed and with the group 'Business' it will add a line in 'groups_customer' with the id_group=3
In case it's a new subscribed and 'Particular' customer, it will add id_group=4
In any other case, it will not add any rows on 'groups_customer'

So this is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER register_client_group  
AFTER INSERT  
ON customer  
FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN  
IF (NEW.`group`='Business' AND NEW.subscribed=true)  
THEN  
INSERT INTO groups_customer (id_group, id_customer) VALUES (3, NEW.id_customer);  
ELSE IF (NEW.`group`='Particular' AND NEW.subscribed=true)  
THEN  
INSERT INTO groups_customer (id_group, id_customer) VALUES (4, NEW.id_customer);  
END IF;  
END;
```

The MySQL said:

```
"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8 "
```

The problem seems to be with the IF statement.

Comment: `group` is a reserved word in mysql and you need to wrap this with backticks ``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GROUP` is a reserved Word in MySQL ([used by the GROUP BY-Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)).

So your Trigger-Function should be:

```
CREATE TRIGGER register_client_group
AFTER INSERT
ON customer
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.`group`='Business' AND NEW.subscribed=true)  
    THEN
        INSERT INTO groups_customer (id_group, id_customer) VALUES (3, NEW.id_customer);  
    ELSEIF (NEW.`group`='Particular' AND NEW.subscribed=true)  
    THEN
        INSERT INTO groups_customer (id_group, id_customer) VALUES (4, NEW.id_customer);
    END IF;
END;
```

If you are using PHPmyadmin remember to change the default delimiter as done in this image. http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-u8TUx_srGrw/TVZp7saqF3I/AAAAAAAAIn8/fvYOaGcxNfY/s640/DELIMITER+MYSQL.jpg

Comment: That's right, but still getting an error:
    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8 

I think it's a problem with the IF ELSE statement, but I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: i added a ; and put another group into `. The rest looks good, see mysql doc for example: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: I finally got the solution.  Your code is almost perfect but you have to delete that space between the ELSE IF (So it is ELSEIF) and if you are using phpmyadmin in order to use a trigger with BEGIN and END statements you have to change the default delimiter as done in this image. http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-u8TUx_srGrw/TVZp7saqF3I/AAAAAAAAIn8/fvYOaGcxNfY/s640/DELIMITER+MYSQL.jpg.

Comment: Adding the delimiter as $$ worked for me according to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258394/if-statement-inside-mysql-trigger