# Syntax error if statement mySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

```
create trigger tr_af after update on relatorio_notas 
for each row
if (new.Nota < 7) then
insert into aluno_af (nome, matricula) values (new.Nota, new.Matricula_estudante)
end if;
```

I got syntax error and I don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `BEGIN` and `END` block in your syntax. See the [13.1.11 CREATE TRIGGER Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html):

```
create trigger tr_af after update on relatorio_notas
for each row
begin               # <-------------------
  if (new.Nota < 7) then
  insert into aluno_af (nome, matricula) values (new.Nota, new.Matricula_estudante);
  end if;
end                 # <-------------------
```

Note you may need to set the delimiter to something different than `;`.

See more info in [MySQL syntax check](http://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/) or a sample in [Trigger syntax and IF ELSE THEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5272184/1983854).